# Creating Bi-weekly appointment in Outlook

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I'm trying to create a bi-weekly appointment using vbscript. But for some reason the output date is always occurring on every other Thursday when it should be every other Friday. I have outlook set up to start the week on a Sunday. I have changed and removed.DayOfWeekMask and it stays on Thursdays.

```
Dim endDate 
Dim startDate

endDate = #01/01/2022#
startDate = #01/01/2012#

Const olRecursBiWeekly = 1 
Const olFriday = 6
Set olkEvent = olkApp.CreateItem(1)

olkEvent.Subject = "Pay Day" 
olkEvent.AllDayEvent = True
olkEvent.ReminderSet = False

Set objRecurrence = olkEvent.GetRecurrencePattern

objRecurrence.DayOfWeekMask = olFriday
objRecurrence.RecurrenceType = olRecursBiWeekly
objRecurrence.PatternStartDate = startDate
objRecurrence.Interval = 2
objRecurrence.PatternEndDate = endDate

olkEvent.Save
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no such thing is olRecursBiWeekly. You need olRecursWeekly  (=1).

olFriday is &H20 (32 decimal).

Comment: Interesting. Funny that just forcing it to be 1 made it work. But if I haven't rearranged the code around like Andy G said it wouldn't of worked either. Wish there was a way to make both your answers the selected answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to move things around:

> The DayOfWeekMask should be set **after** the RecurrenceType property has
>   been set and before the PatternEndDate and PatternStartDate properties
>   are set.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866785%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Andy! The re-arranging did work with the combination of Dmitrys suggestion.